# Are elements made out of many atoms?

Tags: electrons, atoms, elements, protons, neutrons

So im reading a chemistry book right now, and always thought an element is made out of ONE atom, with special properties that make it this element.
Amount of Protons, neutrons and electrons.

But this book now says, "most natural elements are made out of mixes of many isotopes; etc.etc. ..."
So, an Isotope is an atom with more or less neutrons than normal, right?

SO, to my main question, are element made out of many atoms then?
What about lets say, iridium. How many atoms does it know have?

Comment: Google is your friend: search "isotopes of Iridium".

Comment: In case of confusion over textbooks, learn the habit to consult the topic with available offline and online resources before asking. This way you prevent providing redundant information and save resources of other people to tell you, what is  already written in many ways on many places.

Answer (score 1):

Let's take a better known element : Chlorine. It is similar to Iridium, as it is made of two isotopes.

In nature chlorine atoms are made of the two isotopes $\ce{^{35}Cl}$ ($17$ protons + $18$ neutrons) and $\ce{^{37}Cl}$ ($17$ protons + $20$ neutrons). On Earth, the chlorine element is made $75$% $\ce{^{35}Cl}$ and $25$% $\ce{^{37}Cl}$. It means that the chlorine molecules $\ce{Cl2}$ may have the three following compositions :

$9/16$ ($\ce{^{35}Cl-^{35}Cl}$) molecules (mass $70$ u), plus

$6/16$($\ce{^{35}Cl-^{37}Cl}$) molecules (mass $72$ u ), plus

$1/16$ ($\ce{^{37}Cl-^{37}Cl}$) molecules (mass $74$ u).

It means that pure chlorine $\ce{Cl2}$ is made of a mixture of three different molecules, in proportion $9/16, 6/16$ and $1/16$.